# Magento Market place extension

Tags: php, magento

I have a marketplace extension and i want to show seller name on product view page in right side on custom theme.
Seller information shows on default product view page but it does not show on our custom theme's product view page.

Here is my marketplace.xml code:

```
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/wk_block.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
          <block type="core/template" name="wk-block" template="marketplace/wk_block.phtml" before="-"></block>
        </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

code on view.phtml template of my custom theme:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other'); ?>

   <?php if ($tmpHtml = $this->getChildHtml('block_product_primary_bottom')): echo $this->getChildHtml('name');?>
    <div class="feature-wrapper top-border block_product_primary_bottom"><?php echo $tmpHtml; ?></div>
   <?php endif; ?>

   <?php if ($tmpHtml = $this->getChildHtml('product_primary_bottom_placeholder')): //Placeholder for extensions ?>
    <div class="feature-wrapper top-border"><?php echo $tmpHtml; ?></div>
   <?php endif; ?>

  </div> <!-- end: product-shop -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to make an assumption here but I guess in the product template that is being used in your custom theme there is either no right column or in that right column there is no call to the new block `wk-block`.

I would compare the base theme product template with that of your main theme and see if there is anything obviously different.